# Debugging OAuth API Request

Tags: r, api, rest, get, httr

I am trying to use the TradeMe API in R, but I keep getting a 401 error when I make the request. Here is my code:

```
# Install and load needed libraries
library(httr)

# Set keys and secrets
consumer_key <- "my_consumer_key"
consumer_secret <- "my_consumer_secret"
access_token <- "my_access_token"
access_secret <- "my_access_secret"


# Set up the API request
url <- "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/MyTradeMe/Watchlist/All.xml"
auth <- paste0("OAuth oauth_consumer_key=", consumer_key,
               ", oauth_token=", access_token,
               ", oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1",
               ", oauth_signature=", consumer_secret, "%26", access_secret)
headers <- c(Authorization = auth)

# Make the request and store the response
response <- GET(url, headers = headers)

# Check the status code of the response
status_code <- response$status_code
print(status_code)
```

I have double-checked that my keys and secrets are correct and that the OAuth signature method and signature are properly formatted. I have also checked the documentation for the API to make sure that I am using the correct endpoint and that my request is formatted correctly.

However, I am still getting a 401 error. Is there anything else I should be checking or any other potential causes for this error?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for the API you are using? What guide are you following? Every website is different and you have to read the documentation to see what it expects. Do they give you working examples for different languages to use as a comparison?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes I have read it. https://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-overview/authentication

Comment: They don’t give any proper examples from what i can see